# AlarmManager só armazena um Alarme

Tags: android, android-alarmmanager

Estou com um problema relacionado ao `AlarmManager`, por exemplo, se eu programo um Alarme para 16:00 e outro para 16:30 somente o segundo está gerando a notificação, diferente do segundo. Fiz umas conversões um pouco confusas para manipular o horário, mas está funcionando certamente. Segue o trecho em que salvo as informações do Alarme:

```
//ATIVAÇÃO DO ALARME BASEADO NO HORÁRIO QUE O USUÁRIO DESEJAR

Intent intent = new Intent("ALARME_DISPARADO");
PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

//cal = Calendar.getInstance();

//Abaixo faço a conversão das horas e minutos digitados pelo usuário para Millis e depois somo tudo
horasint = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");//Pegando somente o valor "hora"
resulhora = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

minutosint = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");//Pegando somente o valor "minuto"
resulminutos = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

String inthora = ""+horasint.format(resulhora);//Salvando o valor hora em uma string
String intminutos = ""+minutosint.format(resulminutos);//Salvando o valor minuto em uma string

long horamilli = Integer.parseInt(inthora) * 3600000;//Convertendo a string hora para inteiro e convertendo para Millisegundos
long minutosmilli = Integer.parseInt(intminutos) * 60000;//Convertendo a string minuto para inteiro e convertendo para Millisegundos

long paraMEIA_NOITE = (24*3600000) - (horamilli + minutosmilli);//Subtraindo 24h do horário atual em Millisegundos para saber quanto tempo falta para 00:00h

long x = System.currentTimeMillis() - (24*3600000); //Subtraindo o horário atual por 24h em Milisegundos
long y = x + paraMEIA_NOITE;//Adicionando quanto falta para meia noite porém está incompleto faltando a parte que lhe pedi ajuda agora

//COLOCAR CONDIÇÕES AQUI PARA CASO SEJA NO DIA SEGUINTE, OU DOIS DEPOIS, ASSIM SUCESSIVAMENTE

if(auxdia == day)//Domingo - Domingo
{
    long z = y + (Integer.parseInt(edhorario.getText().toString())*3600000) + (Integer.parseInt(edminutos.getText().toString())*60000);//Adicionando a hora que o usuário digitou
    cal.setTimeInMillis(z);
    long teste = z;
    Toast.makeText(this, "- Hora Marcada: "+teste+"\n\n- Hora Atual: "+System.currentTimeMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

else if(auxdia == day + 1)//Tal dia - Um dia depois
{
    long z = y + (24*3600000) + (Integer.parseInt(edhorario.getText().toString())*3600000) + (Integer.parseInt(edminutos.getText().toString())*60000);//Adicionando a hora que o usuário digitou
    cal.setTimeInMillis(z);
    long teste = z;
    Toast.makeText(this, "- Hora Marcada: "+teste+"\n\n- Hora Atual: "+System.currentTimeMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

else if(auxdia == day + 2)//Tal dia - Dois dias depois
{
    long z = y + (2*(24*3600000)) + (Integer.parseInt(edhorario.getText().toString())*3600000) + (Integer.parseInt(edminutos.getText().toString())*60000);//Adicionando a hora que o usuário digitou
    cal.setTimeInMillis(z);
    long teste = z;
    Toast.makeText(this, "- Hora Marcada: "+teste+"\n\n- Hora Atual: "+System.currentTimeMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

else if(auxdia == day + 3)//Tal dia - Três dias depois
{
    long z = y + (3*(24*3600000)) + (Integer.parseInt(edhorario.getText().toString())*3600000) + (Integer.parseInt(edminutos.getText().toString())*60000);//Adicionando a hora que o usuário digitou
    cal.setTimeInMillis(z);
    long teste = z;
    Toast.makeText(this, "- Hora Marcada: "+teste+"\n\n- Hora Atual: "+System.currentTimeMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

else if(auxdia == day + 4)//Tal dia - Quatro dias depois
{
    long z = y + (4*(24*3600000)) + (Integer.parseInt(edhorario.getText().toString())*3600000) + (Integer.parseInt(edminutos.getText().toString())*60000);//Adicionando a hora que o usuário digitou
    cal.setTimeInMillis(z);
    long teste = z;
    Toast.makeText(this, "- Hora Marcada: "+teste+"\n\n- Hora Atual: "+System.currentTimeMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

else if(auxdia == day + 5)//Tal dia - Cinco dias depois
{
    long z = y + (5*(24*3600000)) + (Integer.parseInt(edhorario.getText().toString())*3600000) + (Integer.parseInt(edminutos.getText().toString())*60000);//Adicionando a hora que o usuário digitou
    cal.setTimeInMillis(z);
    long teste = z;
    Toast.makeText(this, "- Hora Marcada: "+teste+"\n\n- Hora Atual: "+System.currentTimeMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else if(auxdia == day + 6)//Tal dia - Seis dias depois
{
    long z = y + (6*(24*3600000)) + (Integer.parseInt(edhorario.getText().toString())*3600000) + (Integer.parseInt(edminutos.getText().toString())*60000);//Adicionando a hora que o usuário digitou
    cal.setTimeInMillis(z);
    long teste = z;
    Toast.makeText(this, "- Hora Marcada: "+teste+"\n\n- Hora Atual: "+System.currentTimeMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


//cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

AlarmManager alarme = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarme.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), p);

//alarme.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 10000, p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Se tens o alarme para 16:00 e outro para 16:30, certamente que terás de criar uma verificação em tempo real para verificar. Por exemplo, terás dois métodos, um que agenda o alarme para as 16:00 e outro para 16:30. E na verificação, verificar se a hora actual do sistema for igual a 16 e o minuto 0, então, dispara o primeiro alarme, caso não, dispara o segundo alarme.

Tive algo assim parecido aqui comigo. Espero ter ajudado ;)

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode agendar dois alarmes com a mesma 'intent action'. Caso faça isso, o anterior será cancelado. Este é um comportamento [previsto](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Aproveitando, ao invés de usar AlarmManager que é altamente verboso, você pode utilizar esta library:

https://github.com/carlosedinazioaraujo/ThinDroid

Feita por este que vos fala :D

Para agendar um alarme basta anotar quantos métodos quiser com:

@AlarmTask(interval = {INTERVAL_IN_MILLI}, wakeUp = {BOOLEAN})
void foo(){}

Basta ler o Readme que tem na página do github, importar o projeto no seu build.gradle e usar a vontade. Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição :D